# Aggregating records by $group - condition 1 or condition 2

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a database of about 50k "company" records.

I want to find duplicates by matching:

1. `name` and `street` fields.

OR

2. `phone` field

(I consider both #1 and #2 unique identifiers, so either can be used to find duplicates.)

I am able to write the $group statement to match based on #1:

```
  _id: {
    name: '$name',
    street: 'street'
  },
  uniqueIds: {
    $addToSet: '$_id'
  },
  count: {
    $sum: 1
  }
```

I tried something like this to match one or the other:

```
_id: { 
 $or: [
  {name: '$name', street: '$street'},
  {phone: '$phone}
 ]
}...
```

But that just returns a boolean.

How to group by filtering for #1 or #2 above in the same aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use $facet:

```
db.company.aggregate([  
{ $facet:{  
by_name_street:[ {$group:{ _id:{n:"$name",str:"$street" }, cnt:{$sum:1} }} ] , 
by_phone:[ {$group:{ _id:"$phone" , cnt:{$sum:1}  }} ]  
} }    
])
```